# can't work fread, getc while reading bytecode of python a byte pertime

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read bytecode instruction  from python pyc file....i calculated code string size(codesize), then use fread

```
char *code = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) *codesize);
fread(code, 1, codesize, fp);
```

but it is getting stuck...and tried with getc()

```
while(i < codesize){
     code[i] = getc(fp);
}
```

this is also getting the same problem while reading bytecode instruction singlebyte perttime..i used the same method for reading normal string it is working good, bytecode instruction reading only getting stuck...

please help me to solve this problem... why this happening? and a sollution to read bytecode instructions...

Comment: In your while loop you don't increment `i`, it will be always true if `i` is initially smaller than `codesize`. And what means `fread()` get stuck? Further it would be helpful to show more of your code.

Comment: The second snippet is wrong as pointed out by @AndreKampling -- about the first it's impossible to tell something. Please create and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Just a shot in the blue: If you are on Windows you have to open the file as binary. (e.g. `fopen("file.pyc", "rb")`) Otherwise, `fread()` will silently replace any `\r\n` by `\n` which probably corrupts your byte code. Thus, if you compare the read size with the size of the file, the former may be less even although all bytes have been read. To be sure, I just tested `while (i < codesize) code[i++] = getc(fp);` and it has the same behavior (of eliminating `\r` which are followed by `\n`).